# Get Value from HTML select box

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want to receive the selected Value from the Selectbox. I tried this. When I'm doing this i receive an empty String.

Html:

```
<div class="selector">

    <select id="values" name="values" runat="server">

        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>

    </select>

</div>
```

C#:

```
String value = Request.Form["values"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should wrap your select in form tag. In case you want get Form values.

```
<div class="selector">
  <form>
    <select id="values" name="values" runat="server">

        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>

    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

Then you can run through all of your form entities by doing this

```
foreach (string key in Request.Form)
```

Comment: I want to get the selected Value in an onClick Method.

Comment: Do you mean onClick on option?

Comment: I want to get the selected Value from the Selectbox when im clicking on my Button.

Comment: You can try to make your button of type submit `<button type="submit">` and put it inside of your form.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
    <select id="values" name="values" runat="server">

        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>

    </select>

</div>
```

c#

```
var values=values.DataSource[values.SelectedIndex][values.DataTextField].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
    <div class="selector">
      <form runat="server">
        <select id="values" name="val" runat="server">
          <option value="--">----</option>
       </select>
     </form>
   </div>
```

C#

```
  int selectop=Page.Request.Form["values"].ToString();
```